# How to speed up building process of NumPy using pip for a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, numpy, pip, dockerfile

I am using GitHub and GitHub Actions to build a Docker container that contains a Python application based on Django.

When doing pip install -r requirements.txt in my Dockerfile it takes ages (up to 10 minutes) to build my Docker Container, as numPy needs to be compiled.

Is there a way to speed this up dramatically?
Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: Find the best-suited tag from [Django repository on `dockerhub`](https://hub.docker.com/_/django?tab=tags), based on your application then use it as the base image. It would probably save you a lot of time.

Comment: Not sure how this is helping with compiling Numpy!?

Comment: This way you do not have to install `django` anymore (thereby don't have to compile `numpy` ). `django` has already been installed by the official django developers on the image. @David

Comment: @meti Still not the point. NumPy is not part of Django and due to security reasons I want to keep my 3rd party library footprint as small as possible.